# Zero Product Theorem - an inequality question regarding the denominator

Tags: inequality

Hey guys so I have this question:

$(12x + 4)^{-1} < 0$

At first look I thought it would just always get back to 0 < 0 with loss of my x, which can't be. I Had a look around and the best I can do is this:

$(12x + 4)^{-1} < 0$

$1/(12x + 4) < 0$

$1/[4(3x + 1)] < 0$

$1/4 * 1/(3x + 1) < 0$

And now... I'm stuck. I know the answer is $x < -1/3$, but I don't see or understand how that can be from where I am?

Answer (score 1):

Now you have $3x+1<0$, since otherwise one have that $\frac{1}{3x+1}>0$. Now continue from this point!

Comment: Is that because one or both 'parts' of the fraction must be < 0? So the only variable part is 3x + 1, therefore that is the part that is < 0? Ok i think it just clicked for me actually. Thank you!

Comment: @Dani The inverse of a positive number is positive, the inverse of a negative number is negative.